# Remove unicode strings in rendered template

Tags: python, django, unicode, unicode-string

I'm trying to return a json like object under this address:

http://ntt.vipserv.org/data/shows

but as a result I'm getting :

{'1': {'url': u'http://www.rte.ie/tv/crimecall/', 'image': u'http://img.rasset.ie/0002c8d0-250.jpg', 'id': u'2', 'name': u'Crimecall'}}

How to get rid fo the unicode strings ?

My code:

```
objects = Show.objects.all()
i = 0
dict = {}
small_dict = {}
for o in objects:
    small_dict = {'id': o.id.decode('ascii'), 'url': o.url.decode('ascii'), 'name': o.name.decode('ascii'), 'image': o.image.decode('ascii')}
    dict[str(i+1)] = small_dict
    small_dict = {}
```

Comment: found it. Just used encode instead of decode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module instead of trying to write a JSON encoder yourself. This will correctly format the strings in double quotes and without the `u` in front of the string.